# Angularjs, on number Input always getting $error.number false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

This is the HTML

```
<form name="productForm" data-ng-controller="productPageController">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="99" id="product-qty" data-ng-model="qty" name="productQty" size="2" class="input-text qty" maxlength="2" />
</form>
```

Inside the controller I have this (it's coffeescript)

```
  $scope.$watch "qty",  ->
   errors = $scope.productForm.productQty.$error
   if errors.number isnt false or errors.max isnt false or errors.min isnt false
   $scope.qty = 1
```

My problem is that if I console.log $scope.productForm.productQty.$error.number I always get false as value, even if the user digits letters into the input. For max and min validation the validation is working

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: False doesn't mean that your value is false it means that you don't have any error on your field

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6t3qwuk/)

Comment: I would actually like to know why it's not behaving like this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nGjpNLyT2RJ3URbT9Apg?p=preview)